# Inequality in a Polynomial

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

This is a problem I made.

> Let $x^3-ax^2+bx-c$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and three real roots, all greater than $1$. Prove, that $b+c \geq 3a-5$.

***Due to the discussion made (see the comments) I will post my solution (this solution does exist!) in a couple of hours***

Comment: Are you serious @Klangen ! If you want, I can send you the solution I found! STOP being suspicious of everyone here! Just because I am new here, this does NOT mean I am a liar, or I want my homework to be done!

Comment: @math_here As much as I believe it is not a homework question, the way you have written it is not the type of post that MSE welcomes. What you can do is add, using MathJax, the solution you have found and ask for alternative solutions. There is even a tag for it: [tag:alternative-proof].

Comment: @TheSimpliFire But If I post my solution (which in fact I think is the only one which can be found for this problem, but anyways) then the interest will fall down. I just wanted to post a nice construction and to see nice solutions ...

Comment: @math_here Unfortunately, asking these "challenges" on MSE is not part of the site's intentions. (Aside) In fact, because of this, I have once tried to create a new SE site for hosting these but it proved unsuccessful.

Comment: @math_here On MSE, we encourage users asking high-quality questions which they do not know the answer to. That is standard. However, I would like to advise you that posting such questions in the future will likely be controversial.

Comment: I have removed a very large number of comments on this question. These comments asked whether or not this question is secretly a homework question, and whether it is reasonable for a user to post a question as a challenge to other users. There is some confusion about the SE policy concerning answering one's own questions. The purpose of both the site and the policy is to provide a useful archive of answers to questions people have. If you have a useful question and its answer, you can put them up at the same time. Using the site as a forum to pose challenges is not well-regarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the cubic
$$
(u+1)^3-a(u+1)^2+b(u+1)-c=
u^3 - (a-3) u^2 + (3-2a+b)u - (c+a-b-1)
$$
has all three roots positive, the coefficients $a-3$, $3-2a+b$ and $a+c-b-1$ are all positive.  Hence
$$
5+b+c-3a=(c+a-b-1)+2(3-2a+b)>0.
$$

Comment: Very nice solution der @user10354138 It's even different than mine!

Answer (score 4):

Let $p+1$, $q+1$, $r+1$ be our roots.

Thus, $p$, $q$ and $r$ are positives and  by using the Viete's theorem we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(p+1)(q+1)+\prod_{cyc}(p+1)\geq3\sum_{cyc}(p+1)-5$$ or
$$pqr+2(pq+pr+qr)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Very nice dear @Michael Rozenberg That's exactly my solution!